# Javascript inside a modal duplicated everytime I open the modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal with a form and javascript inside.

My modal content (called by ajax) :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="action">Submit</button>

<script>
    $('.action').on('click', function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

Everytime I click on my button, I have a lot of alert displayed (not only one), the javascript inside the modal is not reset/killed when I open and close the modal again and again.

Comment: Don't get it -- you have an alert inside a modal, if you open and close the modal lots of times, it will get executed each time you open the modal. Whats wrong with that? Do you not want the alert at all?

Comment: I want reset/kill my JS inside the modal everytime I open my modal. If my .action button inside my modal update a value in my database (by ajax), I dont want have 10 ajax query everytime I click on the button because the JS is duplicated everytime I have open the modal.

Comment: Do you close the alert boxes before closing the modal?

Comment: Yes, it's just an example, if I try with console.log('test') and open/close 5 modal, when I open a new modal I have 5 lines in my console only for this click.

Comment: Can you replicate this on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, I listen the click event not directly on the submit button (button inside the ajax return), but on the modal wrapper and I place my JS **outside** the modal :

> $('#modal-wrapper').on('click', '#my-submit-btn', function () { ...

Now, the JS work and is not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you set the `<script>` tag inside the modal using an AJAX request.  So everytime you call the AJAX request a new `<script>` tag gets executed and a new event is bound to the button. That's why you have multiple alerts showing.

To solve that, just isolate the JS from the modal or just set it once and not set it from the AJAX call. Just make it a static `<script>` tag.

Otherwise destroy the existing event handlers before you bind a new click event. Because events are still bound to the element even if you delete the `<script>` tag.